# Get back to index file in cordova

Tags: php, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created android app using cordova 3.0, In this app form index file I gather the ip address of **localhost** from a input field and then redirect it to a folder which consist files created with php and jquery mobile 1.4 using `window.location.replace` and then perform task according those files. 
the problem is, after accessing **localhost** i want to access the index file to get the page of entering ip address to another ip address. 
Is there any possible way to do that...??

In server side i'm using php and Jquery mobile 1.4

Thank any way..

Comment: the redirected page(localhost) is not a part of your application, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is not a part in my application

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get back to the application if you change `window.location`.

So open the new link in a pop up using [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser).You can do whatever you need in that pop up and return back to your application by clicking done button.

InAppBrowser looks like this

[image]